# Angular html input'ы с общим значением max

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input

Как можно получить событие `input` чтобы остановить ввод `e.preventDefault()`? Или есть какие-то другие способы реализовать подобное?

```js
var maxTotal = 150,
  inputs = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('input')),
  getTotal = function() {
    var sum = 0;
    inputs.forEach(function(input) {
      sum += parseInt(input.value, 10);
    });
    return sum;
  },
  maxReached = function(e) {
    var sum = getTotal(),
      target;
    if (sum > maxTotal) {
      target = e.target;
      target.value = target.value - (sum - maxTotal);
      // next line is just for demonstrational purposes
      document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = getTotal();
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
    // next line is just for demonstrational purposes
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = getTotal();
    return true;
  };

inputs.forEach(function(input) {
  input.addEventListener('input', maxReached);
});
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" />
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" />
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" />

<div>total: <strong id="total">0</strong>/150</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EL4tf/

Comment: что мешает перенести имеющийся код в ангуляр?

Comment: @Grundy, это достаточно красиво ангулярными методами делается :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать директиву, которая будет делать вложенные элементы и контролировать сумму. А можно и по-другому: просто установить ограничение для `ng-model`:

```js
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.a = $scope.b = $scope.c = 0;
  $scope.lim = 150;
  
  ($scope.update = function () {
    $scope.sum = $scope.a + $scope.b + $scope.c;
  })();
})

.directive('mySumLimit', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, el, attrs, ngModel) {
      var old = scope.$eval(attrs.ngModel);
      var lim = scope.$eval(attrs.mySumLimit);

      ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function (val) {
        val = +val;
        
        if (val > lim + old) {
          ngModel.$setViewValue(val = lim + old);
          ngModel.$render();
        }
        
        return val;
      });
      
      scope.$on('destroy', scope.$watch(attrs.mySumLimit, function (val) {
        lim = val;
      }));
      
      scope.$on('destroy', scope.$watch(function () { return ngModel.$modelValue }, function (val) {
        old = val;
      }));
    }
  };
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" ng-model="a" my-sum-limit="lim-sum" ng-change="update()" />
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" ng-model="b" my-sum-limit="lim-sum" ng-change="update()" />
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" ng-model="c" my-sum-limit="lim-sum" ng-change="update()" />

  <div>total: <strong id="total">{{sum}}</strong>/{{lim}}</div>
```

Comment: Замечательно, спасибо! Только только `$scope.a, $scope.b, $scope.c` заменить на один объект, чтобы не было зависимости от количества `input`'ов.

Comment: @Sasay, просто использовать массив и ng-repeat. На приведённую директиву это никак не влияет. Если возникает проблема с биндингами инпутов, задай отдельный вопрос и напиши мне ссылку в комментарии - отвечу.